# Author dropdown change went missing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, author, wordpress-6

Don't know if anyone have the similar problem, but after updating WordPress to 6.0 , changing the post ( or the custom post field ) author  went missing. Does anyone know how to activate it?

Have in mind that there is field in edit, but I would need the same in "Quick Edit"

Thanks

Comment: How many registered users on your WordPress instance?

Comment: ~14K , but have like 20 authors and 4 administrators

Comment: There are some changes in 6.0 for "large sites". https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/05/02/performance-increase-for-sites-with-large-user-counts-now-also-available-on-single-site/ And, I have put together a plugin to help (older versions and 6.0) with the many-users problem.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/